# Modified checkout form for a signed in user of Spree based application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, solidus

Im new to using Spree . We are using Solidus which is a fork of Spree 2.4. I would like to customize the checkout flow in my application. For a signed in user we dont want to show the form for shipping address, billing address, contact information and payment information as we need to prepopulate those fields with the customers information that we have in our database.

I went through the checkout flow docs at https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/checkout.html, but still dont have any idea how i can achieve the above . Can someone please guide me as to how can i modify the checkout form to hide the shipping address, billing address, contact information and payment information for a signed in user ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace or override views frontend with your own version. To generate frontend in your project

```
rails generate spree:frontend:copy_views
```

The checkout views should be in this folder

```
YOUR_APP/app/views/spree/checkout
```

The views are coded with [ruby erb](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.9/lang_template_erb.html).